# After modal view controller dismissed any pushed controller doesn't call viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I use

```
this.PresentViewController(...);
```

to display a modal view controller another controller.
Then on dismiss button action inside the modal view controller I call

```
this.DismissViewController(...);
```

The problem is in that application stops calling viewDidAppear methods in every other controller inside of my NavigationController until I reinitialize it. Actually the problem appears only on iPhone (iOS 5/6).

How to bring application to life after dismissing a modal view?

Comment: This shouldn't happen -- you'll have to post more code, and explain how you set up the UI (storyboard, xibs, all in code?).

Comment: I have a tabbar controller as a root one for iPhone with navigation controller inside.
I call this.PresentViewController(...) from a controller pushed into the navigation.
I wonder maybe navigation controllers' delegate is broken after a modal view is being dismissed?

Comment: Do you see any warnings printed in the console during these transitions?